# Why won't firefox load the webpage when I am listening via proxy and browsing on the same port?

Tags: security, firefox, proxy, burp

As you can see, I have burpsuite listening on 127.0.0.1:8000 and firefox is manually configured to connect through 127.0.0.1:8000. Yet the page will not load.

[image: burp]

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot I can see that it is working, it is just that "Intercept" is enabled.

Click the Intercept tab and turn Intercept off using the button (or click Forward to forward that individual request).

Comment: Ah okay, so is the purpose of "forward" to continue to browse and record all of the traffic and headers?

Comment: Yes, it records everything as long as it is configured as the proxy in your browser.